# Eliyahu HaNavi and bris

Tags: sources-mekorot, brit-milah, baby-infant, eliyahu-hanavi, forgiving-mechilah

Someone once told me that when Eliyahu HaNavi comes to a baby's *bris*, everyone who is presently there is forgiven for their sins.

Does anyone know the source for this?

Comment: See http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=27801 and http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=5956

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Bnai Yissaschar Tishrei 4:2:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14491&st=&pgnum=38&hilite=) mentions regarding all those attending a Bris receiving forgiveness for their sins in the name of a Medrash, however he says he has not seen where this Medrash is.

> כך שמעתי שיש באיזה מדרש ולא ראיתיו

[Rabbeinu Bachya Lech Lecha - 4th line from the bottom](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30834&st=&pgnum=105) says that the Blood of Milah is a Kappara. See also the [following page at the top](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30834&st=&pgnum=106) where he says that since it is a Kappara therefore we make a Seuda.