# Source for forgiveness at a Bris Milah for those who share the baby's name

Tags: sources-mekorot, names, brit-milah

I have heard many times that if one is present at a Bris Milah and the baby receives the same name as them, they receive forgiveness for all of their sins and/or some sort of special Beracha.

Is there any source for this, or is this simply some corruption of what is spoken about here: [Eliyahu HaNavi and bris](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51063/eliyahu-hanavi-and-bris)?

Comment: I've never heard this.

Comment: @DoubleAA interesting.  Everyone else - feel free to chime in if you have or haven't heard this.

Comment: Never heard this either

Comment: Sorry, I haven't heard of this before now as well.

Comment: Thanks guys!  Did anyone who upvoted hear it?

Comment: @DoubleAA #MeToo

Comment: I upvoted, but I haven't heard this. Hmmm ... my cousin's youngest son has the same first (and last name) as me, and I was at his brit many years ago. I'll have to ask him about this, next time I see him. My close friend's oldest son also has the same 1st name as me. When I asked my friend afterwards why they chose that name, he surprised me by saying, "We named him after you, because we love you." I wonder if there's any additional item, besides what you mentioned when that situation occurs.

Answer (score -1):

I think the source is in the book "LECHEM LEFI HATAF", under the entry Shem ([page 307 in this version](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32977&st=%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA&pgnum=307))

Thus, all the guests will want to reach an alliance that the circumcised baby may be called with their name.

And therefore we do not publish the name of the circumcised baby before the BRITH.
And so the commandment will take place BROV AM.

Comment: Hi Termin!  Thanks for your answer.  I'll poke around the two Sefarim on Hebrewbooks with this name to try to find the source, but did you happen to know where in the Sefer it was?

Comment: I did manage to find the same topic discussed, but this answer is not given.  I have edited in the link, so that way you can tell me if you see it there...

Comment: He talks about שפע חיות, but I don’t see anything in there about forgiveness or about people wishing that the baby have their names.